# Selecting a specific field to delete in the mysqli_fetch_assoc output i made

Tags: php, mysql

im in the middle of programming a website and i have a problem in selecting the field i want to delete in my query.
this is what i made.

```
<?php 
$qryprod = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE username = 
'".$_SESSION['username']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
$prodres = mysqli_query($con, $qryprod);
if (mysqli_num_rows($prodres) > 0) {
    while ($prodview = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prodres)) {
        echo '
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="pictures/maxresdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive 
center-block">';
                ?><?php echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-2">Name:
</div><div class="col-md-10">'.$prodview['product_name'].'</div></div><div 
class="row"><div class="col-md-4">Stock:'.$prodview['product_stock'].'</div>
<div class="col-md-8">Price:'.$prodview['product_price'].'</div></div><div 
class="row"><div class="col-md-4">Size:'.$prodview['product_size'].'</div>
<div class="col-md-8">Brand:'.$prodview['product_brand'].'</div></div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-open"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right"  data-
toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-
remove"></i></button>
              </div>

              </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}
?>
```

notice that I queried all the item from the database equal to the $_session['username'].there is not a problem in displaying it.
the problem goes in the deleting part. since i just queried all of it to display it, i want to delete a one from the display i made.

and this is my query to delete.

```
<!-- Change Delete Modal content-->
<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Delete item</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
  <?php $qryprod = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE username = 
'".$_SESSION['username']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
$prodres = mysqli_query($con, $qryprod);
if (mysqli_num_rows($prodres) > 0) {
    $prodview = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prodres));
    }
      ?>
  <h4>Are you sure to delete <?php echo $prodview['product_name'] ?>?</h4>
    <form method="POST" action="store.php">
    <input type="submit" name="yes" value="Yes" class="btn btn-default btn-
lg">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default btn-lg 
pull-right">Cancel</button>
      </form>
  </div>
 </div>
  <?php if (isset($_POST['yes'])) {
 $qry ="DELETE FROM product WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ";
 $qryres = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
 }
 ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

is there somehow a way to pick the desired panel to be deleted?

Comment: In the modal form, use hidden input that will have the value of id of the product table. That will give you the selected product to be deleted. Then your query could be - $qry ="DELETE FROM product WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND id='" . $_POST[id] . "' ' ";

Comment: thanks bro.i found a way by getting an id..